# issue in python (moviepy)

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm using Moviepy to convert Video, Error occurs while doing that

try to change the file location on every drive but still the issue presists

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

clip = mp.AudioFileClip("C:\Galaxy S10- OfficialIntroduction.mp4‪").subclip(30,100)

clip.write_audiofile("D:/hello.wav")
```

```
C:\Users\sanchit\PycharmProjects\mystartup\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/sanchit/PycharmProjects/mystartup/Mp3 TO AUDIO.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sanchit/PycharmProjects/mystartup/Mp3 TO AUDIO.py", line 4, in <module>
    clip = mp.AudioFileClip("C:\Galaxy S10- Official Introduction.mp4‪").subclip(30,100)
  File "C:\Users\sanchit\PycharmProjects\mystartup\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 72, in __init__
    buffersize=buffersize)
  File "C:\Users\sanchit\PycharmProjects\mystartup\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 50, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename)
  File "C:\Users\sanchit\PycharmProjects\mystartup\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 274, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    "path.")%filename)
OSError: MoviePy error: the file C:\Galaxy S10- Official Introduction.mp4‪ could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have file in `"C:\Galaxy S10- OfficialIntroduction.mp4‪"`

Comment: See: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/830

Answer (score 2):

I copied the string verbatim from your question, and
there is an extra non-visible character at the end of your filename (examined in Python 3):

```
In [9]: list((c, ord(c)) for c in
        "C:\Galaxy S10- OfficialIntroduction.mp4‪"[-4:])
Out[9]: [('m', 109), ('p', 112), ('4', 52), ('\u202a', 8234)]
```

It is the [left to right embedding](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) character.
It is almost certain that this is not actually part of the filename, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running video(mp4 file), if it works okay then try

```
(r"C:\Galaxy S10- OfficialIntroduction.mp4‪")
```

or

```
("C:\\\Galaxy S10- OfficialIntroduction.mp4‪")
```

or

```
("C:/Galaxy S10 OfficialIntroduction.mp4‪")
```